# How to handle array of objects passing to socket nodejs client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a nodejs/socket project which require passing of multiple arrays from the server to the client. The client uses Jquery Datatables to built tables from the arrays. If I have just one array object I can pass it ok without using stringify/parse. however, when I have multiple arrays I have a problem.

So I create an object of arrays **myobjectofArrays** and assign all my **objectArrays** to **myobjectofArrays**. So now they can be accessed by **myobjectofArrays.objectArray1.length** for example to give you the length of objectArray1. So far so good. The problem is when I try to send  **myobjectofArrays** with:

```
socket.emit("arrays", {myobjectofArrays:JSON.stringify(myobjectofArrays)})
```

and accept it with:

```
socket.on('arrays',function(data)
       {
        var newdata=JSON.parse(data);
       });
```

I get a JSON parsing error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data.**

The docs speaks to a bad JSON construct but when I do the parsing on the Server side myobjectofArrays return to an object with multiple array properties like before. and the console log of the stringified showed multiple arrays..see sample below:

```
console.log("myobjectofArrys json: "+myobjectofArrays);
```

result:

```
myobjectofArrays json: {**"rpamessageArray"**:[{"messageid":0,"make":"car0","model":"Model0
","part":"Part0","price":"9999.99","instock":false},{"messageid":1,"make":"car1"
,"model":"Model1","part":"Part1","price":"9999.99","instock":false},{"messageid"
:2,"make":"car2","model":"Model2","part":"Part2","price":"9999.99","instock":fal
se},},{"messageid":3,".........,"price":"9999.99","instock":false}],"}],"**ordersArray**":[{"messageid":0,"ordernumber"
:0,"customer":"name0","contact":"555-1230","make":"car0","model":"Model0","part"
:"Part0","price":"9999.99","shipping":"Pickup","payment":"cc-mobile","confirm":t
rue},{"messageid":1,"ordernumber":1,"customer":"name1","contact":"555-1234","mak
e":"car1","model":"Model1","part":"Part1","price":"9999.99","shipping":"Pickup",
"payment":"cc-mobile","confirm":true},{".........]
```

Can anyone tell why am I getting this error? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: don't aspect your json didn't mutate in transit. console.log the data before parse client side and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an expert on socket.io, but ...

Socket.emit() isn't sending JSON. Its sending an Object with one key that is a JSON string

Try to change this

```
socket.emit("arrays", {myobjectofArrays:JSON.stringify(myobjectofArrays)})
```

to this

```
socket.emit("arrays", JSON.stringify(myobjectofArrays))
```